# JQuery Display - Output Statement

Tags: jquery

```
/**
* VARIABLE PRODUCT PRICING TABLE
*/
function rp_wcdpd_switch_variable_pricing_tables(element_id) {
    jQuery('.rp_wcdpd_pricing_table_variation').hide();
    jQuery(element_id).show(); 
}

if (jQuery('.rp_wcdpd_pricing_table_variation').length) {
    jQuery('input:hidden[name="variation_id"]').each(function() {
        rp_wcdpd_switch_variable_pricing_tables('#rp_wcdpd_pricing_table_variation_' + jQuery(this).val());

        jQuery(this).change(function() {
            rp_wcdpd_switch_variable_pricing_tables('#rp_wcdpd_pricing_table_variation_' + jQuery(this).val());
        });
    });
}
```

I have a custom piece of script that I am trying to modify. The function of this is to display a Pricing Table. One product may have hundreds of pricing tables depending on what attributes are chosen. As it stands, it will only show one at a time and only if attributes are selected.

I then modified this to allow the first pricing table to display before anything is selected. This works, but the problem is that when a user selects an attribute it shows two tables instead of the attribute table replacing the first default table.

This is what was added to show the first table as default.

```
jQuery('.rp_wcdpd_pricing_table_variation').first().show();
```

So my question is how can I write this so that the default (First table is hidden) and replaced by the attribute table?